# cast to pointer from integer of different size warning when assigning pointer to function

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

Why do I get this warning when assigning an anonymous function to a pointer to function field in my struct?

Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct list_node_t  {...} ListNode;

typedef struct list_t {
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* current;
    ...
    //pointer to function fields
    int (*hasNext)();
    ...
}List;
```

And here I assign an anonymous function to hasNext. It causes the warning.

```
List* makeNewList( ){
    List* list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    list->current = list->head;
    list->hasNext = (int   (*)(void)) (list->current==list->tail? 0:1);
    return list;
}
```

compiling with gcc -c -Wall list.c respond with this message:

```
list.c: In function ‘makeNewList’:
list.c:35:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     list->hasNext = (int   (*)(void)) (list->current==list->tail? 0:1);
```

Why? I want list->hasNext to be a pointer to a function returning int, not a scalar int. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're assigning values 0 or 1 to function pointer, not pointer to function as it should be.

Comment: `list->hasNext = (int   (*)(void)) (list->current==list->tail? 0:1);` What is this line supposed to do? It doesn't make any sense. Why would you set a function pointer to the value 1?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that C has anonymous functions, with that particular syntax?

You need to put your foot down and actually define the function:

```
static int list_has_next(const List *list)
{
  return list->current == list->tail;
}
```

The function also (of course) has to take an argument, there are no implicit arguments in C. You need to update the function pointer in the structure to become compatible:

```
int (*has_next)(const List *list);
```

Also, [stop casting the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: There's no need to keep a pointer to the same function in every node.

Comment: @n.m. No, of course not, but the OP seems to want one. Perhaps there are different kinds of "has next" checks depending on what goes into the list, or I don't know.

Comment: Oops. misread the code, please disregard. It's in the list, not in the list node.

Comment: Why do I think that C has anonymous functions? K&R shows this syntax when calling a function having pointer to function parameter:

void qsort(void *lineptr, int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
And the invocation:
qsort((void**), listptr, 0, nlines-1,
(int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));

Oh, looking at this again, (numeric?numcmp:strcmp) return one of tow function names. there is no "inline implementation" there.

Comment: Isn't there other way to implement hasNext without sending a list as a parameter?
Any other way to implement an iterator that can support hasNext and getNext without exposing the node implementation to the outside?

A function that has a static list so it can remember current whenever it's called? But can have two instances of that iterator func with different list assigned to their separate static field?

Comment: @Zack This is going [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), fast. :) You should probably re-post. And no, a function's static variables cannot have different values for different parallel callers.

Comment: @unwind, OK, I'll post a new question a bout implementing a List iterator and hiding the List implementation. :)
Thanks.